# How would I design an NFA that recognises the language of all strings that don't end in a certain sequence?

Tags: automata

How would I design an NFA that accepts all strings don't end in a certain sequence over the alphabet {0,1}.
Designing a DFA that does the job is fairly straight forward, but I can't find out how to make my Automata Non-Deterministic.

Answer (score 3):

Any DFA is also already a NFA, so you've already answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually "non-deterministic automaton" is a horrible name. It better be "(finite) automaton" which has a subclass of "deterministic" automata. I do not think people are really interested in the construction of an automaton that is on purpose non-deterministic.

Comment: It's a pretty common convention in mathematics that the "non-" prefix doesn't mean "not" but rather "not necessarily".